# Dependency Injection - To API Controllers

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor

I have a Blazor application that I am using.  The dependency injection works well in the components/pages.  But how can I access a dependency from one of my API Controllers?

Comment: Create a constructor. The parameters will be injected.

Comment: Brian, can you post this as a possible answer, and I will accept it.  It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As your controllers are already injected you only need add a constructor with parameters. The parameters will be injected assuming they are provided.